# Multilingual website URL & SEO

Tags: seo, google, url, canonical-url, permalinks

For example, I see most of the Google's properties is using the `hl` query string, e.g.

```
http://www.youtube.com/?hl=zh-TW
```

and compare the above URL with

```
http://www.youtube.com/zh-TW/..
```

From the SEO and usability perspective, which one is better?

Comment: I advice to read also this discussion: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20729/should-i-make-a-search-engine-only-page-for-my-domain-which-re-directs-visitors/20730

Comment: This is a FAQ on this website: [How should I structure my urls for both SEO and localization](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/403/how-should-i-structure-my-urls-for-both-seo-and-localization))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I my view 2nd one is better because short url are more preferable.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [official documentation from Google](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=182192#1) about multilingual sites. The main point is:

> Keep the content for each language on separate URLs.

As URL parameters tend to be ignored or scored down by search engines, the second URL should be considered better.

Comment: But the 1st one is what GOogle is using..